# Making my matching system thread safe and dealing with concurrency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, thread-safety

I have a system that I am trying to build that matches users up in real-time.  Based on specific criteria, the user's are matched up 1 to 1. I have the following database tables (kind of like a chat-roulette type system):

```
Pool
+UserId
+Gender
+City
+Solo (bool)

Matched
+UserId
+PartnerId
```

When a user enters a certain page, they are added to the `Pool` table with `Solo` set to true.  The system then searches for another user by querying to the `Pool` table and returns the results where `Solo` is true (meaning they do not have a partner) and `Gender` and `City` are also equal to whatever they query.  If a match is returned, put both users in the `Matched` database and turn both of their `Solo` columns in the `Pool` table to `false`.  If they break the connection, they are deleted from the `Matched` table and their `Solo` column will change to `true`.  I am having trouble trying to architect the way this will work with being thread-safe and concurrency. Here are some questions that I got stuck on:

-What if 2 users query the `Pool` database at the same time and both return the same "solo" user?  How do I prevent this?

-What if 1 user queries the `Pool` before a user's `solo` column gets changed, so now that user is returned in the result set, but he is technically not solo

-What other concurrency/thread-safe issues do i face?  Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way to solve this is to wrap your algorithm in a transaction, set the isolation level to serializable and retry the whole business operation in case of a deadlock. This should solve all of your concerns in the question.

Making your application deadlock resistant is not easy in such a complex case. I understand you are just getting started with locking and concurrency in the database. This solution, although not perfect, is likely to be enough.

If you require more sophistication you probably need to do some research around pessimistic locking.

Comment: What do you mean by wrap your algorithm in a transaction? Sorry, I understand what you mean by retrying the business operation if the system detects that there was a conflict, but i don't understand what you mean by wrapping my algorithm in a transaction

Comment: With transaction I mean database transaction. SQL Server and EF support those. It means that all queries including DML that you execute happen under certain guarantees of atomicity and isolation.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the issue is that the "Solo" field is redundant; it simply indicates whether there is a valid entry in the "Matched" table or not. I'd recommend removing it and instead just joining the "Pool" table to the "Matched" table, so you don't have to worry about issues with keeping the two in sync.

Other concurrency issues can be solved by using a concurrency tracking field. See [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Also, just my opinion, but you may want to consider having an "audit" type of table for saving the deleted entries, or switch to using a temporal table for "Matches", rather than simply deleting the entries. That information could be very useful in the future, for tweaking your matching algorithm and such.

Comment: Just turning on some EF options does not solve his particular challenges.

Comment: It is true that simply adding it is not enough; you must also add the appropriate logic to detect the conflicts, and handle them appropriately (the link explains how).

Answer (score 0):

Queueing is a good idea. If each request for a match was queued there would be no contention or dead-lock to query the pool.

Comment: `lock` is a process-level lock. This is not preferrable in a web-application. The app should be stateless and multi-instancing ready.